# PHP issue:Why is there blank output while running this code?And Why is there a 1 in the other case?

Tags: php, output, echo, logical-operators

Using == vs Using !=

```
 /*Testing some basic scenarios in PHP*/

$a=7;
$b=5;
echo $a==$b;



$a=7;
$b=5;
echo $a!=$b;
```

Output is blank screen in case 1.
Output is 1 in case 2
.Why am I getting these respective outputs?

Comment: You better read some stuff from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)

Comment: Try `echo true;` and `echo false;`. The output is 1 and (empty) respectively. You can cast it to int by doing `echo (int)($a == $b);` to get 0 as the output.

Comment: So echo output is in string format,right?Where true is '1' and false is blank?